# Iif in MS access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have two columns in a table like this

```
| Code1 | Code2 |
|-------|-------|
| 3306  | 3210  |
| 3306  | 3111  |
| 4508  | 8888  |
```

I wanna put another column where `iif(Code1 ne 3306;1;iif(Code2 =3210;1;0))`, so that the combination `3306 3210` to get `1`.

The result I want is

```
| Code1 | Code2 | Ncol |
|-------|-------|------|
| 3306  | 3210  | 1    |
| 3306  | 3111  | 0    |
| 4508  | 8888  | 1    |
```

Do you how to put in the where statement or am I doing something wrong with the `iif` function?

Comment: Maybe change `Code1 ne 3306` to `Code1 = 3306`? Are the two fields numeric or text fields? Text would require a `'` around the numbers - `Code1 = '3306'`.

Comment: I was going to add `IIF(Code1=3306 AND Code2=3210,1,0)` because you want the combination of `3306` & `3210` to return `1`, but then your result table has `1` for `4508` and `8888` - how does that work?

Comment: No sorry I didn't say it right. I want 1 either if the combination 3306 and 3210 is true either if Code ne 3306